# shallow copy problem with values and references

Tags: python, shallow-copy

In python I have:

```
x = [1,2,3,[4,5,6]]
y = x[:]

x[3][0] = 9
```

so now:

```
x = [1,2,3,[9,5,6]]
y = [1,2,3,[9,5,6]]
```

but:
x[0] = 99

then:

```
x = [99,2,3,[9,5,6]]
```

and:

```
y = [1,2,3,[9,5,6]]
```

how come when I change an element that's in a list of a list it's reflected in both x an y but when I change an element in a list they are not?

Comment: You mention "shallow" which here means "interior elements are shared references".

Comment: You never changed (mutated) the `int` (you can't , ints are immutable). You simply re-assigned a new object to that index in the list. On the other hand, you mutated the list inside the list, which is bein referred two by both copies (that's why it's a shallow copy). This has nothing to do with the *type* of object at the index, insofar as they are treated specially. It's the same as doing `x[3] = [9,9,9]`. That change will only be reflected in `x`